# Firestore role based security roles not working properly

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Hello I need to configure firestore security roles for my ionic app as shown in [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7PUm7LmAOw). But when it applies to my firestore it always say permission denied.
If i use just WRITE:TRUE its working.

Here is my firestore db
[image]

and Here how i defined security roles according to myone

```
 match /tournaments/{tournamentsID} {
    allow read:if isLoggedIn();
    allow write:if getUserData().roles.keys().hasAny(['subscriber']);
    }

 function getUserData(){
 return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data
 }
```

Now I edited it as

```
allow write:if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.roles.subscriber == true
```

Then its working.

But if i try same thing using a function as following

```
function getRole(role) {
 return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.roles[role]
  }
```

and calling like

```
allow write:if  getRole('subscriber') == true;
```

Its not working

Comment: Please update your question to include the code that is throwing the error. While you're editing, also replace the image of the security rules with the actual security rules as text. Having things as text makes then searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual code/data/rules and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: One thing I notice is that you use `accounts` in your `getUserData()` but your collection is called `users`

Comment: @Badgy yeah here its wrong(now edited). But in db its users

Comment: I just ran the same code you showed you updated it to and it runs fine for me in the firestore rules simulator. I would recommend checking the rest of your code.